# Writing a function that creates a Tkinter Entry Widget, inserts, and configs that Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am building a Tkinter App that will display 40 entries and my code doesn't look good since I am writing the same 3 lines of code for each `Entry`.

```
self.entry_0_1 = GameEntry(self.background, relx=0.15, rely=0.185)
self.entry_0_1.insert(0, "0.0")
self.entry_0_1.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))
```

Custom `GameEntry` Class for customized `Entry` widget

```
class GameEntry(tk.Entry):
     def __init__(self, master=None, state='normal', font='helvetica', bg='white', fg='black', bd=7, selectborderwidth=7,relief="ridge", relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.175):
                  super().__init__(master=master, state=state, font=font, bg=bg, fg=fg, bd=bd, selectborderwidth=selectborderwidth, relief=relief)
                  self.place(relx=relx, rely=rely, relwidth=relwidth)
```

Code below is used for the `.config`

```
reg = self.root.register(callback)
def callback(input):
    regex = r"^\d*\.?\d+$"
    if re.match(regex, input):
        return True
    else:
        self.root.bell()
        return False
```

Code below is the function I wrote to attempted to condense the 3 lines of code that I mentioned at the top of the post

```
def create_insert_config_entry(root, x, y, insert_input, *args):
    cus_entry = GameEntry(root, relx=x, rely=y)
    cus_entry.insert(0, insert_input)
    cus_entry.config(validate=args[0], validatecommand=(args[1], args[2]))
    return cus_entry
```

Here is how I tried to use `create_insert_config_entry` function

```
self.entry_10_3 = create_insert_config_entry(self.background, 0.575, 0.885, "12.12", ["key", reg, "%P"])
```

Here is the error I got in the console

```
File "c:\Users\Mike\Desktop\code\py\main.py", line 71, in <module>
    run = gui.App()
  File "c:\Users\Mike\Desktop\code\py\gui.py", line 249, in __init__
    self.entry_10_3 = create_insert_config_entry(self.background, 0.575, 0.885, "12.12", ["key", reg, "%P"])
  File "c:\Users\Mike\Desktop\code\py\gui.py", line 244, in create_insert_config_entry
    cus_entry = GameEntry(root, relx=x, rely=y)
  File "c:\Users\Mike\Desktop\py\gui.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(master=master, state=state, font=font, bg=bg, fg=fg, bd=bd, selectborderwidth=selectborderwidth, relief=relief)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3035, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'entry', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "entry" command: application has been destroyed
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] that is a single block of code. I don't think we can piece this code together to get this error. This error is saying that the root window has been destroyed and then you try to create an entry widget.

Comment: `self.entry_10_3 = create_insert_config_entry(self.background, 0.575, 0.885, "12.12", ["key", reg, "%P"])` will raise exception `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. It should be `self.entry_10_3 = create_insert_config_entry(self.background, 0.575, 0.885, "12.12", "key", reg, "%P")` instead.